# Python/lxml/BeautifulSoup: using one text string to find another

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm using Python's BeautifulSoup library with the lxml parsing engine to iterate through a bunch of docs on the SEC website (sec.gov). All of the docs contain the text string "(Name of Issuer)" beneath the actual name of the issuer, and I'm trying to use "(Name of Issuer)" to find and scrape the actual name of the issuer from each doc. Trouble is, the HTML/CSS is inconsistent from one doc to the next (sometimes the text is in a `<p>` tag, sometimes in a `<td>` tag, etc.).

I'm trying to use the following try/except block:

```
try:
    issuer = soup.find(string="(Name of Issuer)").parent.find_previous(tag_has_text).string

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error occurred while 'Name of Issuer' for url: {url}, error: {str(e)}")

    continue
```

to parse, for example, this HTML:

```
<P STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; text-align: center">WESTERN MAGNESIUM CORPORATION</P>

<P STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; text-align: center"></P>

<P STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; text-align: center"></P>

<!-- Field: Rule-Page --><DIV STYLE="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; width: 100%"><DIV STYLE="font-size: 1pt; border-top: Black 1.5pt solid">&nbsp;</DIV></DIV><!-- Field: /Rule-Page -->

<P STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; text-align: center"></P>

<P STYLE="font: 10pt Times New Roman, Times, Serif; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt; text-align: center">(Name of Issuer)</P>
```

FYI, the "tag_has_text" argument calls a function that checks whether a tag contains text:

```
def tag_has_text(tag):
    return tag.string is not None and len(tag.get_text(strip=True)) > 0
```

I'm expecting to get, for example, `value = "WESTERN MAGNESIUM CORPORATION"`. Instead, I'm getting a lot of these errors: "Error occurred while 'Name of Issuer' for url: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.htm, error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'," which may indicate that it's not finding "(Name of Issuer)" or it's not finding a parent. Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>[Note that you can shorten *`tag.string is not None and len(tag.get_text(strip=True)) > 0`* to <kbd>**`tag.string and tag.get_text(strip=True)`**</kbd> and expect pretty much the same results.]</sub>

If I test the HTML from your question,<sup>([view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUgf7.png))</sup> it actually does return *`'WESTERN MAGNESIUM CORPORATION'`*; where's the snippet from? Is it from the actual source that your program is fetching?

When I try getting [this field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6ut4.png) from [this link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1801762/000149315221018835/form10-12g.htm), I have to normalize whitespace (*`' '.join(s.split())`* but you can also use regex and then you wouldn't need a lambda expression) because there is a line-break after the first word in the "label" after parsing.

(And btw, I think with some versions you need to pass `text=` instead of `string=`, but I get a `DeprecationWarning` for `text`. Also, I only searched through `p` tags because with some versions of bs4, or with certain parsers, you might end up getting the commented text like *`Field: /Rule-Page`* instead of the name.)

```py
# from requests_html import HTMLSession
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1801762/000149315221018835/form10-12g.htm'
resp = HTMLSession().get(url)
# print(resp.status_code, resp.reason, 'from', resp.url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content)

fieldLabel = '(Exact name of registrant as specified in its charter)'
try:
    fieldVal = soup.find(
        'p', string=lambda s: s and ' '.join(s.split())==fieldLabel
    ).find_previous(  'p', string=lambda s: s and s.strip()  ).string
except Exception as e:
    print('Error finding', fieldLabel, ':', repr(e))
    fieldVal = None
print(fieldVal)
```

prints

> ```py
> WESTERN
> MAGNESIUM CORPORATION
> ```